# Multithreading method calls in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, queue

Say we have a class A and we call its method:

```
- (void)saveCompanyOnServerWithTitle:(NSString *)title {
    [self.interactor performSaveCompanyNetworkRequestWithCompanyTitle:title];
}
```

And Interactor implements the method as follows:

```
- (void)performSaveCompanyNetworkRequestWithCompanyTitle:(NSString *)title {
    typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
    [self.uploadService addUploadOperationWithCompanyTitle:title completion:^(id result, NSError *error) {
        if (error){
            [weakSelf.presenter didPerformSaveCompanyNetworkRequestWithError:error];
            return;
        }
        [weakSelf.presenter didPerformSaveCompanyNetworkRequestWithResponse:result];
    }];
}
```

UploadService's method implementation looks like:

```
- (void)addUploadOperationWithCompanyTitle:(NSString *)title completion:(RCNUploadOperationBlock)completionBlock {
    NSURLRequest *request = [RCNRequestFactory createCompanyUploadingRequestWithCompanyName:title];
    RCNUploadOperationBlock block = ^void(id result, NSError *error){
        if (error){
            completionBlock(result, error);
        } else {
            completionBlock(result, nil);
        }
    };
    RCNCompanyUploadingOperation *uploadingOperation = [[RCNCompanyUploadingOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request
                                                                                             completionBlock:[block copy]];
    uploadingOperation.name = title;
    [self.uploadingQueue addOperation:uploadingOperation];
}
```

Now imagine we call `saveCompanyOnServerWithTitle:` in several queues.
Should I wrap the method call in something like

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_serial_queue, ^{
    [self.interactor performSaveCompanyNetworkRequestWithCompanyTitle:title]
});
```

Or should I just wrap the method's implementation, e.g.

```
typeof(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
dispatch_async(dispatch_serial_queue, ^{
    [weakSelf.uploadService addUploadOperationWithCompanyTitle:title completion:^(id result, NSError *error) {
        if (error){
            [weakSelf.presenter didPerformSaveCompanyNetworkRequestWithError:error];
            return;
        }
        [weakSelf.presenter didPerformSaveCompanyNetworkRequestWithResponse:result];
    }];
});
```

I want to make "addUploadOperationWithCompanyTitle:" calls serial. I know the method itself is an asynchronous one.

Comment: What's your goal? What issue are you trying to resolve?

Comment: My goal is to make method calls guaranteed serial when called from different threads/queues

Comment: As-is, the use of `dispatch_async` won't make them serial because the code being called inside the block is itself also asynchronous.

Comment: Pay your attention at "dispatch_serial_queue". I would use a serial queue in dispatch_async call. I want to make "addUploadOperationWithCompanyTitle:" calls serial. I know the method itself is an asynchronous one.

Comment: The serial queue isn't the issue. It's the fact that `addUploadOperationWithCompanyTitle` is async. So as-is, your use of `dispatch_async(dispatch_serial_queue` buys you nothing without more work.

Comment: I want the method calls to be serial. There is no need to wait for async completion block being called and only after that start another "addUploadOperationWithCompanyTitle" call. 
Say you call "addUploadOperationWithCompanyTitle" from several queues.
If queue A calls "addUploadOperationWithCompanyTitle" and so do queue B and queue C simultaneously I want both of them to wait for queue A performing the method call.

Comment: Based on your last comment, the proposed code in your question seems fine. Either approach works.